# noindex, follow правило для поискового робота и get-параметр

Tags: get, seo, поисковые-системы, robots.txt

мне нужно установить для поискового робота правило `noindex, follow` доступа к страницам, у которых есть `get`-параметр opt. Например, `/propucts` без правила, а к `/propucts?opt` правило применяется.
Будет ли работать вариант вывода `meta`-тега по условию, например

```
if (isset($_GET['opt']))
{
    echo '<meta name="robots" content="noindex, follow">';
}
```

Если этот вариант некорректный, то подскажите, как можно задать `noindex, follow` в `robots.txt` или еще как-то иначе

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, работать такой вариант будет.